# for loop in R - repeating a block of code iteratively

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have a block of code that extracts the top 50 values from a specific column in my dataframe, outputting a new dataframe named accordingly. I want to repeat this process for every column in my dataframe (50-100 columns), as follows. How can I automate this?

```
column1_top50 <- dataframe %>%
arrange(desc(column1)) %>%
slice_head(n = 50) %>%
select(sample_name, column1)

column2_top50 <- dataframe %>%
  arrange(desc(column2)) %>%
  slice_head(n = 50) %>%
  select(sample_name, column2)

column3_top50 <- dataframe %>%
  arrange(desc(column3)) %>%
  slice_head(n = 50) %>%
  select(sample_name, column3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure a for loop would be the most efficient way to do this (purrr would probably be faster). I'll also note that creating a data frame within a for loop is generally frowned upon (if you make an empty placeholder df before the forloop it'd be much faster), but without any sample data I tried to generalize this for the 50-100 columns you said you have:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(sample_name = rep("example", 100),
                x1 = rnorm(100),
                x2 = rnorm(100),
                x3 = rnorm(100)) 
 for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  df1 <- df %>% arrange(desc(.[[i]])) %>% 
    slice_head(n = 50)
  assign(paste0(colnames(df)[[i]], "_top50"), df1[,c(1, i)])
}
```

Comment: this answer gave me the exact same output as my original column-by-column code, but for all columns instantly - it's the exact solution I was looking for

Comment: how would I go about adding a write_csv step to the end of this loop, to write each of the newly-created dataframes to csv? @Laura

Comment: @kerryp add `write.csv(df1[,c(1,i)], paste0(colnames(df)[[i]], "_top50.csv"))` after the line that starts with `assign` but before that last `}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to test without any sample data but here's an option using `purrr::map_dfr`. Where you "loop" through each col in the data.frame and return the top 50 numeric values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(100)

tmp = data.frame(
  col1 = rnorm(100),
  col2 = rnorm(100),
  col3 = rnorm(100)
)

tmp %>%
  map_dfr(~ head(sort(.x, decreasing = TRUE),50))

# A tibble: 50 × 3
    col1  col2  col3
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2.58  2.17  2.73
 2  2.45  1.90  2.61
 3  2.31  1.65  2.55
 4  1.90  1.62  1.88
 5  1.82  1.58  1.79
 6  1.76  1.36  1.35
 7  1.73  1.35  1.35
 8  1.65  1.27  1.24
 9  1.43  1.24  1.23
10  1.40  1.03  1.14
# … with 40 more rows
```

Comment: This is a good way to output the top 50 datapoints from each column. However, the output needs to include the sample name associated with each datapoint (which this output doesn't do). For this reason, I had hoped that a for loop might be possible to run my four lines of code for each column sequentially, outputting a separate dataframe for each column. Is this possible?

Comment: @kerryp - can you provide some sample data? As well as what your expected output is.